# Splitting String by New Line VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that needs to split text in a RichTextBox by a new line. I've tried

`For Each Line As String In RichTextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)`

And I've tried

`For Each Line As String In RichTextBox1.Text.Split(System.Enviroment.NewLine)`

Neither are working. It works if there's only one line of text but not after that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the RichTextBox.Lines property, it is already split for you.

Comment: Thanks! That was simple. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to do it is to use RichTextBox.Lines like so

```
For Each Line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    ' Do whatever
Next
```

Not sure why splitting by Environment.NewLine didn't work for you though, it worked fine for me when I just tested.

Edit: Just noticed the comment on the question, oops. That'll teach me for being slow with posting.